# i have an issue in djangorest profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile') KeyError: 'profile'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'age', 'gender')


class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    profile = UserSerializer(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            first_name=profile_data['first_name'],
            last_name=profile_data['last_name'],
            phone_number=profile_data['phone_number'],
            age=profile_data['age'],
            gender=profile_data['gender']
        )
        return user
```

Comment: Please add sone text explaining your problem and what you tried so far.

Comment: i just tried to signup using postman then this error is occureprofile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
KeyError: 'profile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm guessing the, since in `UserRegistrationSerializer` the field `profile` is not required you have to manage the case it's missing from the `validated_data`

for instance with something similar

```py
 def create(self, validated_data):
        # the second param is the default
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', None)  

        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        if profile_data:
            UserProfile.objects.create(
                user=user,
                first_name=profile_data['first_name'],
                last_name=profile_data['last_name'],
                phone_number=profile_data['phone_number'],
                age=profile_data['age'],
                gender=profile_data['gender']
            )
        return user
```

Comment: its working working bro thanku very much..can u sent your linkedin profile link here

Comment: if it's working mark my answer as the solution so other people can find it. the LinkedIn profile is available here if uoi click on my name